# How to scrape data of a website that requires being logged in and filling a CAPTCHA

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to create a data scraper to automatically read data from a table. However, I need to be logged in to do so.

The web page has input fields for username and password and a captcha like this

[image: CAPTCHA Image]

This is my code so far

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()

data = {'loginName': 'username',
        'password': 'password',
        }

url = 'https://url/api/account/login'
response = s.post(url, data=data)

print(response)
s = requests.Session()
```

I am then planning to use BeatuifulSoup [as shown here](https://towardsdatascience.com/scraping-data-behind-site-logins-with-python-ee0676f523ee)

Right now my response is <Response [400]>.
I think I need to have captchaCode and captchaId in the data, but I am not sure how. I also don’t know if I need to add any headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete the captcha you will need to either use some third party service to complete this or use something like Selenium and fill it out yourself.
One option is to try logging in to the page and using your browser tool see if the page gets the information from some public API, if it does then you can scrape that instead.

Comment: Brilliant. I managed to get the data by looking at the api, like you said. I will try to create a captcha solver now. Any tips?

Comment: Easiest way is to use a service like anti-captcha to solve them although you usually have to pay. If you want to solve the actual image then you would need to look into OCR (optical character recognition) however this is more advanced, bearing in mind that capchas are designed to be hard to solve by computers.